# Missing value when using while loop

Tags: r, while-loop

I apologize in advance for the simple question, but I have not been able to find a solution for a while.
I am trying to find the least common multiple of f0 and f1. 
Here is my code:

```
f0 = 200
f1 = 300

a = f0
b = f1
r = 0

while (a!=b) {
r = a %% b
a = b
b = r
}
```

From this, I get:

```
Error in while (a != b) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Comment: `library(schoolmath)` has an `scm` function that calculates the least common multiple and `gcd` that calculates the greatest common denominator

Comment: You should get in the habit of using <- instead of = for assignment in r

Comment: Thank you for your comments! The schoolmath package did what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Because after the second iteration r = NaN

```
100 = 300 %% 200
0 = 200 %% 100
NaN = 100 %% 0
```